# C# logical error in my program?

Tags: c#, if-statement, passwords

my programs gives no errors yet it doesn't work, it asks for a name and password when then quits the command window.

Any help please ?

```
namespace password
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String Samsonpass = "12345";
            String Riazpass = "hyperion";
            String mypass = "CSGOPRO";
            String Samson = "Samson";
            String Riaz = "Riaz";
            String Curstin = "Curstin";

            Console.Write("Enter your name :");
            string answer = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Enter your password :");
            string password = Console.ReadLine(); 

            if (answer == Curstin && password == mypass)
            {
                Console.Write("Welcome Curstin");
            }
            else if (answer == Riaz && password == Riazpass)
            {
                Console.Write("Welcome Riaz");
            }
            else if (answer == Samson && password == Samsonpass)
            {
                Console.Write("Welcome Samson");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.Write("Invalid user or password !");
            }


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Because it has nothing left to do, so it will exit. If you need to keep it open, consider trying something along the lines of `Console.ReadKey();` at the end of your program.

Comment: Call the program exe directly in the command shell. Then the command window will not be closed and you can see the output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your mistake was very simple, you forgot put `Console.ReadKey();` or `Console.ReadLine();`, Simply it doesn't close the program as soon as you finish the code.

Second I recommend you use a ***switch***, I am not very sure if the variable name is very relevant on this app, It isn't an username, Is it?. You have to do something like this:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write("Enter your name: ");
        string answer = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Enter your password: ");
        string password = Console.ReadLine();

        switch (password)
        {
            case "12345":
                Console.WriteLine("Welcome " + answer);
                break;

            case "hyperion":
                Console.WriteLine("Welcome" + answer);
                break;
            case "CSGOPRO":
                Console.WriteLine("Welcome " + answer);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        Console.ReadKey();

    }
```

Switch Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t.aspx
Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much ! You were of great help :)

Answer (score 1):

It does work, but it closes since it is finished. Put a Console.ReadLine(); at the end.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, simply add a console.readline() at the end of the program as shown below. This will force the program to stop and give you time to see your output.

```
namespace password
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {  
                String Samsonpass = "12345";
                String Riazpass = "hyperion";
                String mypass = "CSGOPRO";
                String Samson = "Samson";
                String Riaz = "Riaz";
                String Curstin = "Curstin";

                Console.Write("Enter your name :");
                string answer = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.Write("Enter your password :");
                string password = Console.ReadLine(); 

                if (answer == Curstin && password == mypass)
                {
                    Console.Write("Welcome Curstin");
                }
                else if (answer == Riaz && password == Riazpass)
                {
                    Console.Write("Welcome Riaz");
                }
                else if (answer == Samson && password == Samsonpass)
                {
                    Console.Write("Welcome Samson");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.Write("Invalid user or password !");
                }
                Console.Readline();

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess it works ok it simply ends to fast.
Try to add ReadLine at the end (and edit the poseted code ;) it looks messy )

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities to pause your Code after finishing:

1. Put a `Console.ReadLine();` at the end of your code. Or:
2. Start your application with Ctrl + F5.